# Funding choices webview not showing ads

Tags: webview, ads

We implemented Google Funding Choices for cookie consent by GDPR. When using desktop or mobile browser, the consent popup is showing and if you agree with the consent you see ads and everything is ok.
But when opening app in mobile (webview application) the popup of consent is not showing. Maybe someone knows what need to do more in webview app?